# How to access specific voxels that satisfies the specific condition in ITK C++?

Tags: c++, image-processing, itk, medical, simpleitk

I have a 3D image and a sphere equation. I need to take out all the voxels that are outside the circle and want to apply a transformation to them. How do I differentiate those points from all the points? I'm not understanding how to actually write the code to access each voxel that satisfies my criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from this [iterator example](https://itk.org/ITKExamples/src/Core/Common/IterateRegionWithAccessToIndexWithWriteAccess/Documentation.html). Use `image->TransformIndexToPhysicalPoint()`. Apply your sphere equation to physical point coordinates to determine whether a pixel is inside or outside. If you want to modify pixel values, `it.Set(newValue);` should do it. Possibly look at other [iterator examples](https://itk.org/ITKExamples/src/Core/Common/index.html).